# Problem with UIButton in orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation

I have one button that I need to locate it for each orientation in different location.
here I have

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if (interfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitDown)
button.frame=CGRectMake(150.0f,150.0f,55.0f,55.0f);
else
button.frame=CGRectMake(100.0f,100.0f,55.0f,55.0f);   
 return YES;
}
```

It worked for the first rotation, when I rotate IPad again button goes to another location.
for example in UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait the button goes not  here (150.0f,150.0f,55.0f,55.0f)
How can I fix this issue? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean "goes to another location"?

Answer (score 0):

The name of your parameter in the method is `interfaceOrientation` but you are checking `orientation`. You should be checking `interfaceOrientation`:

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { 
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitDown) {
         button.frame = CGRectMake(150.0f, 150.0f, 55.0f, 55.0f); 
    } 
    else {
         button.frame = CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, 55.0f, 55.0f);
         return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: So was that the problem? You fixed it and it works now? Or you just mispasted it?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` and `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitDown`

But the correct enumeration name is `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIInterfaceOrientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if (interfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
button.frame=CGRectMake(150.0f,150.0f,55.0f,55.0f);
else
button.frame=CGRectMake(100.0f,100.0f,55.0f,55.0f);   
 return YES;
}
```

Comment: UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitDown doesn't even exist. Yet another mis-pasting error from the OP? I give up on this one, totally pointless if OP can't even get us his code in one piece.